# Mock private final static object with Mockito/PowerMockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I'm currently trying to mock a private final static object within a class. It doesnt seem like my object is being mocked properly.

Example:
Code: In main class

```
public class Main {

    private final static serviceA obj = new serviceA();

    public somemethod { return true; }

}
```

Mocked: In my test class I have

```
Public class TestMain {

    private Main mainObj;
    private static  serviceA obj;

    @Before
    public void setupBeforeTest() {

        obj = Mockito.mock(serviceA.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(serviceA.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(obj);
        mainObj= Mockito.spy(new Main());
    }
}
```

But obj doesnt return the values I specify when doing

```
Mockito.when(obj.returnsFalseMethod()).thenReturn(false);
```

and will actually run the code for `obj.returnsFalseMethod()`.

Any advice would be helpful, also i cannot change any code in the Main class, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize you have to prepare the class creating the object. I was preparing every class except the class instantiating the object.